# conditional probability of a sum or iid normal random variables given a bound on a subset of them

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X_i$ be iid normal random variables with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma$. Is there a straightforward formula to compute the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i < a\:\vert\: \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}X_i < a)$?

If someone can give me a hint, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a strong last name...

Comment: You can reduce the problem to two independent random variables

Comment: Here is an exact result for the integral that comes up in the computation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Integral_of_error_function_with_Gaussian_density_function Just read it right-to-left.

Comment: And http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60805/integral-over-error-function-and-normal-distribution

Comment: Thanks for your help, @A.S. The approximation looks very good. But how can I use it with an upper bound $a$ rather than $\infty$?

Comment: I see. Not sure about exact integral then. Notice that in last @Graham's integral $\phi_1(x)$ is somewhat tightly concentrated around $0$ (basically $0$ for $x>6$) and $\Phi_{n-1}(a-x)$ is slow varying, so you can expand it linearly in $x$: $\approx \int_0^{\infty}\phi_1(x)(\Phi_{n-1}(a)-x\phi_{n-1}(a))$ which can be computed exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k X_i$ where $\{X_i\}\mathop{\sim}^\textsf{iid}\mathcal{N}(0,1^2)$

Since $\{X_i\}$ are iid, then $X_k$ and $S_{k-1}$ are independent.

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S_k< a\mid S_{k-1}<a) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(S_k<a \cap S_{k-1}<a)}{\mathsf P(S_{k-1}<a)}\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(S_{k-1}+x <a \cap S_{k-1}<a)\;f_{X_k}(x)\operatorname d x}{P(S_{k-1}<a)} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\int_{-\infty}^0 \mathsf P(S_{k-1}<a)\;f_{X_k}(x)\operatorname d x+\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathsf P(S_{k-1}<a-x)\;f_{X_k}(x)\operatorname d x}{\mathsf P(S_{k-1}<a)}\\[1ex] & = \dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac{\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathsf P(S_{n-1}<a-x)\;f_{X_n}(x)\operatorname d x}{\mathsf P(S_{n-1}<a)}\\[1ex] & = \dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac{\int_{0}^{\infty} \Phi_{0,n-1}(a-x)\;\phi_{0,1}(x)\operatorname d x}{\Phi_{0,n-1}(a)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, I reached a similar expression. So, in any case, there is no way to avoid evaluating the integral numerically?

Comment: @Iliya You can give good approximations for large $a$ (set $\sigma =1$) compared to $k-1$. For example if $a<<-(k-1)$ (a ratio of $5$ suffices), then condition $S_{k-1}=\sum \sigma_{i=1}^{k-1}X_i<a$ tightly restricts $S_{k-1}$ to right below $a$. Since $E(S_k)\approx a-\frac 1{2a}$, probability you seek could be approximated by $\frac 1 2+\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}2a}$. You can compute this more precisely (and for $a>>k-1$) using asymtotic expansion of the erfc function. For general $a$, find where the integrand is maximized (use $\phi'=-x\phi$) and approximate $\Phi$ in its neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\sum_{i = 1}^{k - 1} X_i$ by $Y$ and $X_k$ by $Z$, by iid assumption and the reproduce property of normal distribution, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(k - 1)\sigma^2)$. The required probability is 
\begin{align}
P(Y + Z < a | Y < a) = \frac{P(Y + Z < a, Y < a)}{P(Y < a)}
\end{align}
in which the denominator is easy to evaluate and you can use a double integration to evaluate the numerator (note $Y$ and $Z$ are independent).

In detail, let $\phi$ and $\Phi$ be the pdf of cdf of a standard normal random variable respectively, it follows that
\begin{align}
& P(Y + Z < a, Y < a) \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{a - z} \phi_Y(y)\phi_Z(z)dy dz \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(\frac{a - z}{\sqrt{k - 1}\sigma}\right)
\phi\left(\frac{z}{\sigma}\right) dz
% = & \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{k - 1}\sigma^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{a - z} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2(k - 1)\sigma^2}y^2 - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}z^2\right]dy dz
\end{align}
the denominator is just $\Phi\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{k - 1}\sigma}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks @Solitary. Although I think the upper bound in the last integral is $a$.